# How do I ask about a job for a company I used to work for?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, career-development, job-offer, reinterviewing

A lot of people from upper management moved to company A from company B and as a result have a good working relationship with one another and are still in contact.

Exactly a year ago I worked for A as an intermediate. This was my first job in the industry for ~5 years and I was great at it.

During the time I was interviewing at B (a year ago), A was internally discussing to promote me to a senior role (unbeknownst to me).

Halfway through my interview process at B, someone in the HR department at A found out I was interviewing there and notified me that A fully supports whatever my decision is, but they were also offering me a senior role. I declined, believing that I did not have enough experience and (luckily passed the interview) started working at B as an intermediate.

As I grow older I would like to live in a house and cease living in an apartment, and due to my city, owning a house is impossible. Ultimately, if I could work remotely (~3 hours away) for a company located in this tech sector I would be content. B does not offer permanent remote working, you must be in the office during core hours.

Just now, A has contacted me, informing me of a senior programmer role and that I would be the perfect fit. From old colleagues, I know this Accommodates remote workers, but I do not know if this role would be supported by it.

I would like to ask them if I would be able to work remotely under this role, however, I do not want to get my name on a piece of paper in their office, only to be notified by someone at B that I've only been here for a year and am already prospecting new jobs. I already experienced that between these 2 companies and it's very awkward.

A is contacting me through a recruiter whom I have never worked with. I still have other contacts on social media from A who I am friends with. Should I just ask them about it instead?

Comment: The advantage of naming things A and B, apart from hiding the real identity is that you don't need to prefix what you're talking about every sentence. And bold tags also shouldn't be used in this way as it only serves to distract the reader. I've improved your formatting but I think your question is off-topic here and the on-topic versions have been asked and answered before. Check the related questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can leverage your personal network for information, then do so. It's one of the main reasons for developing one. Judgement call on how accurate the information is, but I can often learn up to date information in several industries just by asking the right people informally.

Company specific information can be even easier to acquire. It's a personal network that gave away the fact you were applying last time. I've had a similar thing happen to me where I showed up for an interview and the receptionist was immediately on the phone to my boss.

Answer (score 0):

depends on your relationship with the colleagues on social media. If you are close friends with them and know they care about your well-being (even if it's only one person) then I would consider asking them.

Alternatively, I would entertain the idea of asking Company A through the recruiter about your remote worker situation and consider it that way.

Otherwise if you think your position with Company B might be at risk if they find out that you are prospecting, then I would revisit the idea of buying a house and thinking about a timeline when that would realistically be viable (2+ years more at Company B potentially)